# window.onerror=function like directive in actionscript to capture errors?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder

before i begin, i should mention my actionscript skills are about a 5/10. that being said, if you point me in the right direction, i should be able to figure it out.

is there a way of capturing actionscript errors in a window.onerror like fashion?

i already have an amf based logging system setup, both the sending and recieving end are working 100%. so getting the message to the server is taken care of. just need to know if its possible to capture the errors.

i would like to capture any and all actionscript errors, and log them so i can debug them if need be.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're targeting Flash Player >= 10.1, you can use the [LoaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvents.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) object.

```
loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, function(ev:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(ev.error);
}
```

[More examples here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html).